is it possible to add an action button on a notification when using customview for the the notification?
i used first a simple notifcation with content text then i added an action button which works normally but when i added a customview instead it does not seem to work
val notificationView = RemoteViews(context.packageName , R.layout.notification_item)
            val notificationViewBig = RemoteViews(context.packageName , R.layout.notification_item_big)

            val intent = Intent(context,NotificationBroadCastReciever::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("notificationID",matchId.hashCode())
            }
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)


            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"main_chanel")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground) // todo: change
                     .addAction(R.drawable.albania,"stop watching",pendingIntent)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationView)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(notificationViewBig)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setWhen(0)
                    .build()


i have tried searching , but it seems that nobody is using  it with with custom view , so i'm wodering is it possible ? how to do it if yes?
